# First connection to debian server slow

Tags: linux, debian, dns

I have a running Debian web server with ispconfig. The problem is that whenever I make a first connection it takes about 1-2 seconds to connect, after this 1st connection everything runs smoothly.

I suspect it has something to do with the DNS configuration.

How could I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to lookup your server's hostname at a client and your client machine's hostname at a server. If one of two takes long to lookup then you should change that hostname or add it to the /etc/hosts.

To know hostname of the server type `hostname` in the command line. Then on another server type `nslookup <hostname>`. If you get the IP address in the command's output — hostname resolves correctly. Example:

```
$ nslookup google.com
Server:     192.168.0.1
Address:    192.168.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 173.194.70.102
```

If hostname cound not be resolved you'll get answer like this:

```
$ nslookup google.local
Server:     192.168.0.1
Address:    192.168.0.1#53

** server can't find google.local: NXDOMAIN
```

Comment: how can i do that? can you provide me the commands? thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer, added needed information.